# По разному работает сервлет

Tags: java-ee, tomcat, servlet, glassfish

Есть простейший сервлет, который в методе doGet(...) выполняет перенаправление на jsp страницу

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/hello.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Запускаю из под Idea, под GlassFish все отрабатывает отлично, а под Tomcat выпадает с ошибкой

```
    HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception

type Exception report

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getMapping()Ljavax/servlet/http/Mapping;
    www.JSPServlet.doGet(JSPServlet.java:15)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M17 logs.
```

В логах сервера что-то невразумительное, гуглить не получается. Версии серверов - последние.

Comment: В директории Tomcat/lib находится servlet-api.jar?

Comment: @ВикторБоровлёв   Да, находится

Comment: В Idea в настройках Tomcat, во вкладке конфигурации, в библиотеках указано подключение servlet-api.jar? Должно быть выполнено два условия, версия servlet-api выше 3 и установление зависимости для Tomcat.

Comment: @ВикторБоровлёв  Да, все есть.  Это в первую очередь проверял

Comment: @ВикторБоровлёв   Виктор, а какие именно для томката нужны зависимости?  Может я что-то упустил?

Comment: Посмотрите ещё в папке Tomcat/webapp/ваше app или ROOT/WEB-INF/lib наличие javax.servlet-api-3.X.X. Это последнее место, которое пока могу назвать. Уточните, чем собиарете проект, maven?

Comment: @ВикторБоровлёв   в ROOT/WEB-INF/lib  все есть.  Не помогает. Я поэтому сюда и написал, уже два дня пытаюсь сам решить, все перепробовал.  А какие зависимости нужны для томкат?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59366/discussion-between---and-tariel).

Answer (score 0):

В Idea в настройках Tomcat, во вкладке конфигурации, в библиотеках ,было указано подключение servlet-api.jar. Добавил библиотеку javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar и все заработало. В причинах так и не разобрался.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

И все равно работало через раз. Поставил версию томката М21, теперь работает стабильно.